# Submit form with Javascript throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this really frustrating problem. I want to submit a form with Javascript and no matter what I try I always end up getting `Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById('loginForm')' to object`.

I've been staring at this code for some time now and I really can't figure it out. I'm sure it's really simple, but I just can't see the solution.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="do.php?a=signin" id="loginForm">
  <input name="usr" class="test" placeholder="Användarnamn" type="text" />
  <input name="pwd" class="test" placeholder="Lösenord" type="password" />
</form>

<span class="test"><a href="fblogin.php"><img src="gfx/ico/fb.jpg" alt="" /> Logga in via Facebook</a></span>
<span class="test"><a href="javascript: doLogin();"><img src="gfx/ico/Unlock.gif" alt="" /> Logga in &#0187;</a></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doLogin() {
        document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

What am I missing!?

Comment: Copied as it is, your example works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdgj3/), so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Me too. It's working for me.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: It works for me too, on jsfiddle. I use Opera 12.10, but I've also tested it in IE8 and the problem shows up there as well.

Comment: So IE is the one that fails, and only IE?

Comment: @JanDvorak I suppose the error message is of Opera's taste. Pretty confusing, too, as `null` (returned by gEBI) is, well, an _object_.

Comment: @Perplexor The problem is that `document.getElementById()` doesn't find that element, that's all. Check your code for typos (make sure cases are the same).

Comment: The fiddle submits for me in IE8 mode as well

Comment: There where no typos. I just found the problem. I had accidentally added a second `<form>` in my code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @raina77ow!

Comment: try after  putting  `</form>`  after `<span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I accidentally had entered another `<form>` earlier in my code. I removed it and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add **name** attribute to your form

```
  <form name="loginForm" ...>
```

and then apply below.

```
 document.forms["loginForm"].submit();
```

OR

```
 document.loginForm.submit();
```

**tip:**

> You can not have the buttons named submit and use submit(). The
>   buttons override the method. Rename the buttons to something else and
>   it will work.

Comment: I've tried both of them but none of them works. I tried them again now just to make sure, and they didn't do it this time either.

Comment: `document.loginForm` is not universal, and thus not recommended. Stick to `getElementById`

Comment: Also, doesn't `document.forms.` switch by name, not ID?

Comment: but `getElementById` should have found the correct element as well.